# Java copy directory slow

Tags: java, file-copying, apache-commons-io

I have several folders of size >2.5GB on C drive which is SSD. Through Java, I'm moving these folders to another shared drive which also happens to SSD using `FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(sourceDir, destiDir);`

It works fine but is slow (taking ~30 mins) when compared to windows default move option which takes 5 mins. I googled around to see if there is a better way to increase the performance of moving directories through my java program but no luck. Can someone suggest me the best way to move these directories?

Comment: When you say "shared" are you implying that the destination directory is on a network share?

Comment: @Ian, yes it's on a network share

Comment: more specific, it's a NAS (Network-attached storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is what I did

Used a robocopy command within java to copy directories between two locations. Tested with a ~9GB file and was able to copy in ~9 mins. Below is the code snippet

```
 String sourceFolder = new File("C:\\test\\robocopytest\\source\\20170925T213857460").toString();
        String destFolder = new File("C:\\test\\robocopytest\\destination\\20170925T213857460").toString();
        StringBuffer rbCmd = new StringBuffer();
        if ((sourceFolder != null) && (destFolder != null))
        {
          if (sourceFolder.contains(" ")) {
            if (sourceFolder.startsWith("\\")) {
              sourceFolder = "/\"" + sourceFolder.substring(1) + "/\"";
            } else {
              sourceFolder = "\"" + sourceFolder + "\"";
            }
          }
          if (destFolder.contains(" ")) {
            if (destFolder.startsWith("\\")) {
              destFolder = "/\"" + destFolder.substring(1) + "/\"";
            } else {
              destFolder = "\"" + destFolder + "\"";
            }
          }
          rbCmd.append("robocopy " + sourceFolder + " " + destFolder);
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(rbCmd.toString());
        }
```